# JavascriptでDB接続処理を行う場合の、処理を同期させる方法について

Tags: javascript, node.js

例えばjavascriptで、以下のようなDB接続 → レコード取得 → DB切断という関数を順番に走らせた場合、DBに接続が成功する前に、処理が全て走ってしまう可能性があります。

```
function getRecord(){
  var value;

  dbConnect();         // DBに接続する処理
  value = findRecord(); // レコードを1件取得
  dbDisConnect();      // DBを切断する処理

  return value;
}
```

このような場合、一般的にはどのように処理の同期を取るのでしょうか？

callbackは関数の実行の順番をコントロールできそうですが、実行した結果が終わるのを待ってくれ無さそうです。

promiseで処理が成功したらresolve()を走らせるように、上手く関数を繋げるように書くのでしょうか？

それとも、setTimeoutで処理を遅らせたりするのでしょうか？

まさか、whileでグルグルして時間稼ぎするとか。。。

Comment: 質問のコードでは、再帰呼び出し(getRecordの中でgetRecordを呼び出す）をしているので、dbConnectが最初に乱発され、valueは結局最後のgetRecordで得られたものだけが伝搬されて返っていくという動作なると思います。　根本的に見直した方が良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 処理が全て走ってしまう可能性があります、というのは何故そう思われたのでしょうか。DB接続やレコード取得が非同期に行われることをどこかで読んだのなら、その結果の受け取り方も併せて書いてありそうなものですが・・・。

Comment: @Fumu7 さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。申し訳ありません。書き間違えました。

Comment: @unarist さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。仰るとおり、非同期で行われるのを何処かで読んだので、そう思いました。確かに、そういう処理ができる部品なら、受け取り方も書いてありそうですね。使う日が来たら確認してみます。